# When trying to generate a model with Rails and PostgreSQL, the command hangs without error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

When using this command:

`rails generate model Event name:string`

Nothing happens, and I have to CTRL+c.

The versions I'm using are:

- Ruby 2.1.1p76
- Rails 4.1.0
- PostgreSQL 9.3.4
- Mac OS X 10.9.3

I've verified that Postgres is working and I can connect to it by running `psql easyEventTracker_development`. I setup my rails project by running `rails new easyEventTracker -d postgresql`

When running `rake db:create`, I get the following message:

> easyEventTracker_development already exists
>   easyEventTracker_test already exists

Contents of the database.yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: easyEventTracker_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: easyEventTracker_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: easyEventTracker_production
  username: easyEventTracker
  password: <%= ENV['EASYEVENTTRACKER_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

If I setup the project using Rails with SQLite, everything works fine.

Comment: I guess you can't generate any Model (check this). `I can connect to it` - how did you check this? Show your `database.yml`

Comment: Try running the `rails console` and access some of your existing models, that should verify you are connected to PostGreSQL.

Comment: I think he has no models (tables).

Comment: Have you created the database already? `rake db:create` if not, does rails have the correct rights to create the database?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and I've edited the question appropriately.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There is a bug in Spring with Rails 4.1 which causes generators to hang.

Try running `spring stop` and running the generator again.

Comment: Could you kindly paste the url to the issue? Thanks

Comment: Great answer, should I start Spring again after the successful migration?

Comment: Same with rails 5-alpha. Great answer!

Comment: Still the same with Rails 5 beta 3. It didn't happen everytime, but happen to me once.

Comment: Same with Rails 5.0.0rc1

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are not providing `username` and `password` for your development and test databases. You should verify you are able to connect to your database using

```
rails dbconsole
```

which will provide a database specific SQL-prompt that uses the credentials you provide in `database.yml`. While `sqlite3` is a file based program which does not need login credentials you will need them even for development mode if you use a database that is able to use different schema.

If you set up your development schema to work without a password you will still need to provide the schema name as username as in

```
username: easyEventTracker_development
```

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me and I wasn't using Spring so the solution didn't work.

I just quit the console, opened it up again, ran the same command and it worked.